# Is there any way to achieve a hold listener on a Card view which is used in a Recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to achieve an options menu which would hover over a card view if the user holds the card view or presses the settings button. The menu I am trying to achieve should look like this:

[image: https://prnt.sc/or39gv]

I already have set up, the adapter for the recycler view, the setting button when pressed opens the pop-up, which opens a small pop up with the options. However, I am trying to achieve that it would be more of an attached to the card-view, rather than a new window with the selections.

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotesHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return;
        }

        String noteT = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.COL_TITLE));
        String noteC = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT));

        holder.noteTitle.setText(noteT);
        holder.noteDescription.setText(noteC);
        holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        holder.noteCard_settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"The position is:"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, view);
                MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                NotesDbAdapter mDbAdapter;
                mDbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(mCtx);
                mDbAdapter.open();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.popup_edit:
                                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You pressed edit note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.popup_delete:
                                mDbAdapter.deleteNoteById(position+1);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You pressed delete note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
```

```java
public class NotesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView noteTitle;
    public TextView noteDescription;
    public CardView cardView;
    public Button noteCard_settingsButton;

    public NotesHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        noteTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.note_titleView);
        noteDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.note_contentView);
        cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.notes_cardView);
        noteCard_settingsButton = view.findViewById(R.id.note_card_settings_button);
    }
}
```

This code works, don't get me wrong, but I just wanted to know if there is a way in achieving something similar to the image I attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly simple the way I'd do it.

Just hide the custom options view on top of the cardview item by default.
And show the option view when long pressed on the card view.

Why overcomplicate?

Please note I said custom options view.
Meaning, instead of inflating the menu, make it inside XML.
Hope it helps in some way.
Cheers!